# How to Configure the VS Service Reference Tool for iOS and Android?

Tags: web-services, xamarin, wsdl, cross-platform, taskfactory

How do you configure the VS Service Reference tool for generating full asynchronous method (TaskFactory?) classes for iOS and Android development from a VS-generated WSDL to support await functions accessing SOAP services in addition to UWP's being generated in a Xamarin cross-platform solution?

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/).

Comment: I have been referring to that documentation, but the issue is that it doesn't discuss how to configure the tool to produce async methods that return actual responses instead of methods returning no(void) response for the iOS and Android projects. The "ToDoASMX" example project shows both the iOS and Android projects using a "TaskFactory" approach for reaching out to the web service, and speaks of using the tool for generation of the WSDL and reference.cs files.